# Using sample_weight in TensorFlow

Tags: time-series, tensorflow2.0

I am having hard time fitting a Time Series where labels (not the features) are missing.

The problem I would like to fit is: a patient takes one or two tablets every day (the X values). The patient can occasionally monitor their medicine concentration in their blood (the labels). The patient measures this value of concentration every few days (e.g. between 2 and 14). Therefore, Time Series will consist of X with the number of tablets taken every day, and a label every few days. The aim of my model is to predict the medicine concentration based on the history of tablets taken.

In Keras I am trying to use LSTM with the `sample_weight_mode='temporal'` option in .compile, and the `sample_weight` option in .fit (as suggested on [StackExchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64482/training-lstm-for-time-series-prediction-with-nan-labels)). Unfortunately the fit does not seem to apply the weighting correctly.

For now I am working on a toy dataset, where the labels are the sine function of the time values.

Then I randomly introduce 10% of missing values. I set those values to -1 just to flag them as invalid.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime
from random import random

#Simulate Time Series on 3000 days
time_ = np.arange(0, 3000, 1)/10
labels = 1 + np.sin(time_) + time_*0.01

# Simulate 10% of missing labels. Mark them with -1
ind_nan=np.random.choice(len(labels), int(len(labels)*0.1), replace=False)
labels[ind_nan]=-1

#Create sample_weight, an array of 1's with 0 on the missing labels
sample_weight=np.ones(len(labels))
sample_weight[ind_nan]=0
#Create dataframes with data and weights
df = pd.DataFrame({'labels': labels})
sample_weight_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(sample_weight=sample_weight))

#Train/Test Split
train_size = int(len(df) * 0.8)
train_df, test_df = df.iloc[:train_size], df.iloc[train_size:]
train_sample_weight, test_sample_weight = sample_weight_df.iloc[:train_size], df.iloc[train_size:]
print(len(train_df), len(test_df))  #2400 600
print(len(train_sample_weight), len(test_sample_weight)) #2400 600
```

I am using the `create_dataset method` from [this tutorial](https://www.curiousily.com/posts/time-series-forecasting-with-lstms-using-tensorflow-2-and-keras-in-python/).

```
def create_dataset(X, y, time_steps=1):
    #From this tutorial https://www.curiousily.com/posts/time-series-forecasting-with-lstms-using-tensorflow-2-and-keras-in-python/
    Xs, ys = [], []
    for i in range(len(X) - time_steps):
        v = X.iloc[i:i+time_steps].values
        Xs.append(v)
        ys.append(y.iloc[i+time_steps])
    return np.array(Xs), np.array(ys)

# reshape data and weights to [samples, time_steps, n_features]
X_train, y_train = create_dataset(train_df, train_df.labels, 10)
X_test, y_test = create_dataset(test_df, test_df.labels, 10)
sample_weight_train, _ = create_dataset(train_sample_weight, sample_weight_df.sample_weight, 10)
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape, sample_weight_train.shape) #(2390, 10, 1) (2390,) (2390, 10, 1)
```

The train data and weight look fine:

```
#Quickly check that the weight array is 0 where X_train is -1 i.e. missing
X_train[17,:,0]
sample_weight_train[17,:,0]
```

This is the model. I set `shuffle=False` in .fit, because apparently the [validation data is never shuffled](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#is-the-data-shuffled-during-training).

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
  units=128,
  input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])
))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))
model.compile(
  loss='mean_squared_error',
  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    sample_weight_mode='temporal'   #Weights
)


history = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    epochs=30,
    batch_size=16,
    validation_split=0.1, #last 10% of the data
    verbose=0,
    shuffle=False,
    sample_weight=sample_weight_train #(samples, sequence_length)
)

#Predict on test
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
#Plot
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(18,10))
plt.scatter(time_[0:train_size], train_df, color='k', label='train')
plt.scatter(time_[train_size:], test_df, color='b', label='test')
plt.scatter(time_[train_size+10:], y_pred, color='r', label='y_pred')
plt.legend();
plt.xlim([200,300])
```

LSTM can easily fit this time series when I do not have any -1/missing labels (not shown, just run this code with 0 instead of 0.1 in `random.choice` above). However, with 10% missing labels the predictions are off. The model seems to try to fit the missing labels/-1.

Why does the weight fail to work properly?

[image: prediction]

Comment: only for curiosity... did you consider an intelligent method to fill the NaNs and use a standard train (without weights)?

Comment: I do not think interpolating the missing values would work, for example

Comment: I don't know how exactly your real data look like... but I'm thinking about a Kalman Filter to fill the missing value. I used it often for this task

Comment: Interesting but it sounds like it wouldn't work with sparse labels, eg max 2 labels per week. or am I wrong?

Comment: I image a freq of max 2/7 (weekly), why not if u have a discrete amount of data... u can also evaluate to take of periodicity in this way (if present)